# Dynamic Reconfigure - Can I Set An Array Of Values?

Tags: dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to use `dynamic_reconfigure` in one of my nodes, however, one of my parameters is actually a variably-sized array of doubles. Can `dynamic_reconfigure` support variably-sized arrays, or does it only handle name-value pairs and structures?

Would a service with custom message type be a better solution for setting the array?

Thank you for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/138231/dynamic-reconfigure---can-i-set-an-array-of-values?/) by [trianta2](https://answers.ros.org/users/8336/trianta2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 293 on 2014-03-10

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Know it's been a long time but:
You can't have an array of values, however, you can use a string with a comma deliminator between the values.

For example

```
gen.add("vals", str_t, 0, "A comma delimited list", "1,2,3,4")
```

later on you can [break it into an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265581/parse-split-a-string-in-c-using-string-delimiter-standard-c) in your code. In python it's really ease, just use `you_string.split(',')`

---

Originally posted by [Oded](https://answers.ros.org/users/21280/oded/) with karma: 105 on 2016-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tanasis](https://answers.ros.org/users/29349/tanasis/) on 2020-11-30**:
anything changed here since 2016?